# Improving the program smoothness [experiencing crash when loading too much data]

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, matplotlib, python-multithreading

Basically, I'm creating a graph with Matplotlib displaying live data every second. The program works just fine (quite smooth - no errors found) as it's initiated. However, after a certain time, the program starts lagging, and finally not responding (my assumption may be by loading too much data?). I'm trying to achieve the ability to handle massive data for my program. What I've done was removed the grid and hide X-axis from the chart, also used `thread` to run the function separately. It feels like helping just a bit, not much, still experiencing crashes after leaving it on for a while.

If anyone has any suggestions on how could I improve the program to run smoothly please do advise. I've highly appreciated it in advance.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from concurrent.futures import thread
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mplcursors
from mpl_interactions import zoom_factory
import threading 

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()
ax = plt.gca()

def animate(i):
    
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y = data['total_1']
    
    line = plt.plot(x, y)
    
    plt.setp(line,linewidth=0.5, color='r')
    mplcursors.cursor(hover=False)

threads = []
for i in range(1):
      thread = threading.Thread(target=animate, args=(i,))

thread.start()
threads.append(thread)
    
disconnect_zoom = zoom_factory(ax)
plt.title('Live Data')
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 8    
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.grid(False)    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Here's the example of data.csv (time and value) every second new data will be accumulated

```
x_value,total_1

02:22:30-08/16/22,-0.049

02:24:00-08/16/22,0.079

02:24:02-08/16/22,0.081

02:24:03-08/16/22,0.083

02:24:04-08/16/22,0.084

02:24:05-08/16/22,0.073

02:24:06-08/16/22,0.073

02:24:07-08/16/22,0.073

02:24:08-08/16/22,0.073

02:24:09-08/16/22,0.083
```

Comment: Have you considered using some external tool to monitor memory usage? Also, it doesn't look as though the thread is helping in any way

Comment: External tool in terms of hardware you mean? I believe it isn't necessary since memory usage can be viewed on Task Manager.

Comment: By "external" I mean something other than Python. So what does Task Manager tell you about memory usage? Is it a problem? Is it CPU bound?

Comment: After I monitor the memory usage while running the program. The result was 14.4 GB /15.9 GB (91%) of the memory has been used. Would that possibly relate to the problem? Should I consider upgrading/increasing RAM, which might be a solution?

Comment: The idea of reading the whole `.csv` file every time you update the plot doesn't sound very sound. I'd rather read the file at once, then from `animate` try to read past the end of file, and trying again (after a timeout) if an EOF error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good strategy because you are accumulating data on the plot through plt.plot().
The best way to go about this is, before calling plt.plot():

1. get the axes:

   ax = plt.gca()
2. get the lines in the axes:

   lines = ax.get_lines()
3. remove the lines:

   lines[0].remove()
4. add the new line:

   line = plt.plot(x,y)

This would prevent the graph from including too many lines (also, maybe this is not the best strategy, depending on how big data.csv gets).
Also, the thread is not doing anything really.

**EDIT**

I have tried to modify your code as little as possible. But I have removed the thread inclusion, which didn't feel like a sensible choice.
Try the code below and let me know:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from concurrent.futures import thread
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import threading 
import mplcursors


plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()
ax = plt.gca()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y = data['total_1']
    # removal of previous lines
    ax = plt.gca()
    lines = ax.get_lines()
    if len(lines) > 0:
        lines[0].remove()

    line = plt.plot(x, y)
    
    plt.setp(line,linewidth=0.5, color='r')
    mplcursors.cursor(hover=False)

i = 1
animate(i)
    
plt.title('Live Data')
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 8    
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.grid(False)    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT 2**

I have modified the code to take advantage of the *set_data* method on the line primitive. This should speed things up a bit.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from concurrent.futures import thread
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
#import threading 
import mplcursors


plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()
ax = plt.gca()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y = data['total_1']
    # removal of previous lines
    ax = plt.gca()
    lines = ax.get_lines()
    if len(lines) == 0:
        plt.plot(x,y,c="r")
    else:
        lines[0].set_data(x,y)

    mplcursors.cursor(hover=False)

i = 1
animate(i)
    
plt.title('Live Data')
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 8    
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.grid(False)    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please kindly demonstrate where these steps should be located in the code?

Comment: Sure. Please provide two incremental examples of data.csv though.

Comment: Highly appreciated, the post has been updated with the example of two incremental of data.csv

Comment: Added a tentative solution.

Comment: The program feels smoother than before and no longer experiences crash - Many thanks to you. The only problem is it takes quite a bit of time when it freezes - will have to wait. Indeed it's a tentative solution. I will continue looking into an alternate solution in terms of hardware that might relate to memory usage. Do you think that's relevant?

Comment: added a second edit. Let me know how that goes. I don't think it's a memory problem (unless the computer you work on is really really old). Consider that plotting in general is a very expensive operation. Also, if you have multiple lines, you are going to have to modify the code a bit to account for those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247333/discussion-between-tino-and-tham-tantisunthorn).